# With the DocuSign API call CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates how do you match a recipient with the role in the template?

Tags: docusignapi

My template has one role defined. I'm trying to send an envelope based on the template and filling in the name and e-mail for that one role so that the user does not have to place their own signature block.

The problem is that it adds a second signer to the envelope. Then the second signer that got the email asking them to sign must manually place their signature because the signature block was defined for only the first signer.

I started with the code here: https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Sending%20Group/CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates.htm

Here is the code I have. This is Java code.

```
            // just get the first template for now
            EnvelopeTemplates templates = port.requestTemplates(accountId, false);
            String templateId = templates.getEnvelopeTemplateDefinition().get(0).getTemplateID();
            EnvelopeTemplate template = port.requestTemplate(templateId, false);

            // get the existing recipient from the template
            Recipient recipient = template.getEnvelope().getRecipients().getRecipient().get(0);
            recipient.setEmail("asdf@example.com");
            recipient.setUserName("John Doe");
            ArrayOfRecipient1 recipients = new ArrayOfRecipient1();
            recipients.getRecipient().add(recipient);

            ArrayOfCustomField arrayOfCustomField = new ArrayOfCustomField();
            CustomField f = new CustomField();
            f.setName("masterRecordId");
            f.setValue("1");
            f.setShow("false");
            arrayOfCustomField.getCustomField().add(f);

            // define envelope info
            EnvelopeInformation envelopeInformation = new EnvelopeInformation();
            envelopeInformation.setSubject("test email subject");
            envelopeInformation.setAccountId(accountId);
            envelopeInformation.setEmailBlurb("test email blurb");
            envelopeInformation.setCustomFields(arrayOfCustomField);

            // define template
            ArrayOfTemplateReference arrayOfTemplateReference = new ArrayOfTemplateReference();
            TemplateReference templateReference = new TemplateReference();
            templateReference.setTemplate(template.getEnvelopeTemplateDefinition().getTemplateID());
            templateReference.setTemplateLocation(TemplateLocationCode.SERVER);
            arrayOfTemplateReference.getTemplateReference().add(templateReference);
            EnvelopeStatus status = port.createEnvelopeFromTemplates(arrayOfTemplateReference, recipients, envelopeInformation, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The piece that was missing is that you have to add a TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment as well. Here is that piece of the code:

```
            TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment trra = new TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment();
            trra.setRoleName("Stake holder");
            trra.setRecipientID(recipientId);
            templateReference.getRoleAssignments().getRoleAssignment().add(trra);
```

Following is the complete working code:

```
            // create envelope from template
            EnvelopeTemplates templates = port.requestTemplates(accountId, false);
            String templateId = templates.getEnvelopeTemplateDefinition().get(0).getTemplateID();
            EnvelopeTemplate template = port.requestTemplate(templateId, false);

            ArrayOfCustomField arrayOfCustomField = new ArrayOfCustomField();
            CustomField f = new CustomField();
            f.setName("masterRecordId");
            f.setValue("1");
            f.setShow("false");
            arrayOfCustomField.getCustomField().add(f);

            // define envelope info
            EnvelopeInformation envelopeInformation = new EnvelopeInformation();
            envelopeInformation.setSubject("test email subject");
            envelopeInformation.setAccountId(accountId);
            envelopeInformation.setEmailBlurb("test email blurb");
            envelopeInformation.setCustomFields(arrayOfCustomField);

            // define template
            TemplateReference templateReference = new TemplateReference();
            templateReference.setRoleAssignments(new ArrayOfTemplateReferenceRoleAssignment());
            templateReference.setTemplate(template.getEnvelopeTemplateDefinition().getTemplateID());
            templateReference.setTemplateLocation(TemplateLocationCode.SERVER);

            BigInteger recipientId = BigInteger.valueOf(1);

            // define the recipient info
            Recipient recipient = new Recipient();
            recipient.setID(recipientId);
            recipient.setEmail("jane@example.org");
            recipient.setUserName("Jane Doe");
            recipient.setType(RecipientTypeCode.SIGNER);
            ArrayOfRecipient1 recipients = new ArrayOfRecipient1();
            recipients.getRecipient().add(recipient);

            // this links the recipient above with the role in the template
            TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment trra = new TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment();
            trra.setRoleName("Stake holder");
            trra.setRecipientID(recipientId);
            templateReference.getRoleAssignments().getRoleAssignment().add(trra);

            // make the API call to send off the envelope
            ArrayOfTemplateReference arrayOfTemplateReference = new ArrayOfTemplateReference();
            arrayOfTemplateReference.getTemplateReference().add(templateReference);
            EnvelopeStatus status = port.createEnvelopeFromTemplates(arrayOfTemplateReference, recipients, envelopeInformation, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the recipient role defined on your template you need to reference that instead of creating a new one here in your code.  I think the two recipients are 1 from template + 1 from code.

Set the recipient.roleName to match the name you gave it on the template.

Comment: I did that. The role name is exactly the same. First I tried specifying it in the code, copied from the template in the DocuSign GUI. Then I tried the above which gets the recipient from the Template object and only changes the name and e-mail. I checked and the role is the same as the one in the template.

Comment: Is there working code anywhere that shows how to make it see that the recipient in the signer is the same recipient defined in the template.

Comment: You have to add a TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment. This is missing form the sample code here: https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Sending%20Group/CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates.htm